# How do I rename a UDF partition?

Tags: udf

I've formatted a removable USB drive using UDF and would like to rename the partition. Currently the name of the drive is `LinuxUDF` on each machine I access it on. How can I rename the partition, preferably using command line tools?

Answer (score 0):

Use **udflabel** which is available from [udftools](https://github.com/pali/udftools) project since version 2.0. **udflabel** can change label of the UDF filesystem.